# Split array of numbers into 9 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array such as:

`[ 3, 6, 12, 16, 26, 36, 37, 42, 54, 59, 61, 68, 71, 83, 88 ]`

I would like split into 9 different arrays based on ranges 1-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-79, 80-90.

Just like a 1-90 bingo card would be set up.

What is the best way to do this with Javascript?

Comment: how the final output will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the value of the division by 10 as index and collect the values. To avoid to add `90` to a new slot, you could take a minimum as index and adjust the index.

```js
var array = [3, 6, 12, 16, 26, 36, 37, 42, 54, 59, 61, 68, 71, 83, 88, 90],
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, v) => (r[Math.min(8, Math.floor(v / 10))].push(v), r),
        Array.from({ length: 9 }, _ => [])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: +1. Just curious about one thing. Why would you prefer `Array.from({ length: 9 }, _ => [])` over `new Array(9).fill([])`?

Comment: @MohammadUsman, just habit. maybe a performance test would help ...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for such a quick response!